# How to fix this error while trying to build a ns3 simulation?

Tags: linux, networking, simulation, adhoc, ns-3

I have a simulation called adhoc-simulation.cc in a folder called scratch so it should be running fine, however when I build it using this command `sudo ./waf --run adhoc-simulation` in the ns-3.33 folder I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/*/ns-3-allinone/ns-3.33/build/ns3/yans-wifi-helper.h'
```

Comment: You will have to do an ns3 build to get `ns-3-allinone/ns-3.33/build/ns3/yans-wifi-helper.h` : Like `./build.py --enable-examples --enable-tests` / `./waf configure --build-profile=optimized --enable-examples --enable-tests` https://www.nsnam.org/docs/tutorial/html/getting-started.html .......... ns3-users https://groups.google.com/g/ns-3-users

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error using latest version of ns3,I used **./ns3 run filename** command,it worked for me.